# How to query a document library with document sets by name

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a document library which documents are actually document sets each one.

The only way to diferentiate each item is with the column called name, which is actually a guid.

I need to query with that column, but in the UI, it tells me that its a file.

The next code, I tried also with type = Text. but it didnt work.

```
SPList agendaPoints = subSite.GetSafeListByName(MeetingsCommon.Constants
                      .LISTS_X);
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = string.Concat(" <Where>", "<Eq>", "<FieldRef Name='Name' />", 
                            "<Value Type='File'>" + name + "</Value>","</Eq>",
                            "</Where>");
```

The exception is: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: One or more field types are not installed properly

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can query with document set using "Document Set ID".

see this link might be helpful for you.

http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/2010/09/26/querying-document-sets-using-spsitedataquery/